# SQLITE3: converting IDs to codes when there are hundreds of columns to convert

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table A that has several hundred columns (let's say 301 for example) with the first column being the primary key and the rest being IDs from table B i.e.

```
CREATE TABLE "A" (
        ko_index_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
        ko1 INTEGER NOT NULL,
        ko2 INTEGER NOT NULL,
        ...
        ko300 INTEGER NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (ko_index_id)
);

CREATE TABLE "B" (
        id INTEGER NOT NULL,
        name INTEGER NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

I would like to be able to convert the IDs into names. For example:

```
SELECT name FROM B WHERE id in (SELECT * FROM A);
```

Except the `SELECT *` part means that ko_index_id will be fed into `B` which is wrong. If there were only two columns in `A` I could just write

```
SELECT name FROM B WHERE id in (SELECT ko1, ko2 FROM A);
```

but table `A` has 300 columns!

Can anyone help me around this?

Comment: You have a lousy data structure, so you need to copy your code 300 times, once for each column.  If you used a junction/association table, then this would be easy.

Comment: Write a for loop in a programming language of your choice, that prints from `ko1` to `ko301` with commas in between and copy and paste this output.

Comment: @stickybit Thanks fo rthe suggestion but I want to avoid this if possible. Plus I think there is a limit to the amount of characters it can take for one statement.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @GordonLinoff I think you're right but I can't think a decent structure. Could you suggest one? Even if it's just rough so I'm on the right track.

Comment: how about three columns: pk, key name, and key value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

300+ columns? How about redoing `table A` by pivoting those columns into rows. You could have key name and value column. For example:

```
select * from A: 
id, ko_name, ko_value
1,  ko1, 5
1,  ko2, 6
```

Then selecting the keys becomes much easier; e.g:

```
SELECT name FROM B WHERE id in (SELECT ko_value FROM A where ko_name in ('ko1', 'ko2')) ;
```

Comment: This makes sense but how well will it scale? For example what if my original table had 10, 000 rows? Your table will now have 300*10,000=3,000,000 rows. What if the original table had 1,000,000 rows? I would be querying by both id and ko_value.

Comment: It will scale well, but that needs the space of another question. That said, Sqlite3 can actually outperform other databases engines with this kind of simple key/value table.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @Gordon's comment. If you can afford to change your data model, I would suggest you use an intersection table. It's the typical way to model "many-to-many" relationships in a database.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE "A" (
        id INTEGER NOT NULL,
        ...
        PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE "B" (
        id INTEGER NOT NULL,
        name INTEGER NOT NULL,
        ...
        PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE "AB" (
        a_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
        b_id INTEGER NOT NULL
);

SELECT A.id, B.name 
FROM A
INNER JOIN AB ON A.id=AB.a_id
INNER JOIN B ON AB.b_id=B.id;
```